# Commutativity of Contracted Tensors Relations

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

This is a basic question as I am just starting to learn how to work with tensors. I wanted to know whether a sequence of tensors fully contracted together commutes i.e.:

$$\tag{1}  A^a_{\ b}B^b_{\ c} C^c_{\ a} = A^a_{\ b}C^c_{\ a}B^b_{\ c}, $$
where the Einstein summation convention is assumed through out. I imagine this is true as both addition and multiplication are commutative. Furthermore however, if indeed 
$$ A^a_{\ b}B^b_{\ c} C^c_{\ a} = A^a_{\ b}G^c_{\ a}B^b_{\ c}, $$
could one then conclude

$$\tag{2} C^c_{\ a} = G^c_{\ a},$$
i.e. $C=G$ as tensors or would this only hold up to some commutation relation?